# Can FileManager.default.urls(for:in:) be used to get tmp/ directory in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, nsfilemanager

I've successfully used the following to get the `tmp/` directory in iOS:

```
let path = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
```

API docs would seem to prefer we use FileManager to get the `Documents/` directory:

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
```

Is there a way to use `FileManager.default.urls(for:in:)` or something similar to get the `tmp/` directory in iOS?  I tried `.itemReplacementDirectory` and `.url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:)`, but they didn't work.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Swift 3, iOS 10

Comment: Since the docs for `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory` doesn't show anything related to the "temporary" folder, probably not.

Comment: @rmaddy, Thanks!  That's exactly what I was thinking.  However, I found the answer (pls see below).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct answer is simply:

```
let tmpURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
```

Sometimes, you just need to take a break and come back to it later...  =)

Comment: OK, but that doesn't use the `urls` method which is what your question is asking about. Perhaps your question should ask if `FileManager` can be used instead of specifically asking about `urls`.

Comment: Naming path a url object it is very misleading, BTW to get its path you would need to get `path.path`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for drawing attention to your answer in the duplicate.  I couldn't find it on my own, and I tried for quite some time.  You're right about the path name, so I edited it.  It was an arbitrary name taken from a tutorial, but point taken.

Comment: @rmaddy That's true, but I did request that "or something similar."  I appreciate the time you took to try to resolve my issue, though!

Comment: it only supports ios 10 above